# I want to show code snippet after clicking button react js material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to show my code snippet after clicking the button in material ui

```
                    <CardContent align = 'left'>
                        <h2 align = 'left'><TextFieldsIcon/> Input Fields</h2>
                        <hr/>
                        <TextFields/>
                    </CardContent>
                </Card>
                <IconButton aria-label="show" align = "right"> 
                            <CodeIcon/>
                </IconButton>
```

[I want my output to be like this after i click the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8m7M.png)

Comment: You can use some packages, you have a list of code editors, check thiis https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=react-code-editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

<IconButton onClick={()=> setShow(!show) aria-label="show" align = "right"> 
                         { show ?   <CodeIcon/> : null}
      </IconButton>
```

Comment: I want to show the code snippet below the icon. I tested here its replacing the current icon with the div content

Comment: Thank you i modified it!

Answer (score 0):

```
const [contentVisible, setContentState] = useState(false);

toggleCardContent = () => setContentState(!show);    

<Card>
 {contentVisible ? (
  <CardContent align = 'left'>
   <h2 align = 'left'>
    <TextFieldsIcon/>
    Input Fields
   </h2>
   <hr/>
   <TextFields/>
   </CardContent>) : null}                   
</Card>
<IconButton
  aria-label="show"
  align = "right"
  onClick={() => toggleCardContent()}
> 
  <CodeIcon/>
</IconButton>
```